# Ошибка при сборке gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-uglify, gulp-concat

Работаю на linux ubuntu 16.04
При запуске gulp появляется ошибка

```
> template@1.0.0 gulp /media/Data/GitHub/template
> gulp

sh: 1: gulp: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! template@1.0.0 gulp: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the template@1.0.0 gulp script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/igor/.npm/_logs/2018-04-26T14_57_52_348Z-debug.log
igor@Usus:/media/Data/GitHub/template$
```

Ниже мой gulp файл

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
//var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var del = require('del');

var paths = {
   scripts: ['js/**/*.js'],
   styles: ['css/**/*.css']
};

gulp.task('clean', function() {
 return del(['build']);
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles)
      .pipe(concat('main.min.css'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(cssmin())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() { 
  return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(uglify()) 
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js')) 
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts, ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(paths.styles, ['css']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно понятно написано же:

> sh: 1: gulp: Permission denied

У вас нет прав либо на запуск `gulp`, либо на доступ в директорию

```
  /media/Data/GitHub/template
```